# Export Header and Footer

Tags: headers, export, footer

I want to export the header and footer from WordPress as HTML with same the design: CSS, images, JavaScript files.

But not main content page. I want to do this, because I will use the same design in the future.

Can any one give ideas for my requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm doing the same thing for my themes. I'm currently using twenty fourteen as a base for my child theme. What I do, I create 2 folders, namely `css` and `functions`.  Say for instance I putting custom code in the footer, I will create a `footerstyle.css` in my css folder and a `footer-functions.php` in my functions folder, and register/enque these in my main `functions.php` template.  All styling and coding goes into those templates that is specific to my footer.  I also make a note in my `footer-functions.php` where exatly this code must go and how it should be used in my `footer.php` template.  I do this for widgets functions, header functions, general functions etc. My theme has got about 10 of these functions template. It is also easy if I need to change my code for something specific, for instance, if I need to change something in my footer I know I need to go to my footer specific function template.  All other theme related styling and funtions goes into the default `style.css and funtions.php`. So after all said, when twenty fifteen is released, I copy my `functions.php, functions folder and css folder` to my new child theme for twenty fifteen, delete all the twenty fourteen specific code from my `functions.php` template and do all the minor tweaking and I'm good to go. Hope this helps

Comment: thanks for ur quick reply and i have planned to go with ur ideas.